# How to use "class" instead of "ID" in jQuery .each() function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get value of subtotal field in my table, currently i am using table ID in .each function but my table ID  increments dynamically on each section added, that is why i am not able to get value of subtotal and add  each subtotal to get grand total.

This function is adding sub_totals to get grand subtotal

```
function calculateTableSum(currentTable) {
    var sum = 0;

    $('#' + currentTable + ' input.sub_total').each(function() {
        //add only if the value is number
        if(!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length!=0) {
            sum += parseFloat(this.value);

        }
    });
    //.toFixed() method will roundoff the final sum to 2 decimal places
    $('#' + currentTable + ' input.sumamtcollected').val(sum.toFixed(2));
```

This is where is want to use table class instead of table ID

```
  $('#' + currentTable + ' input.sumamtcollected').each(function() {
        //add only if the value is number
        if(!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length!=0) {
            grand += parseFloat(this.value);
            alert(this.value);
        }
```

This is my table

```
<table id="addaccount'+counter+'" class="table table-bordered"><tbody> <tr class="invoice-total" bgcolor="#f1f1f1"><td colspan="3" align="right"><strong>Sub-Total</strong></td><td><i class="fa fa-inr"></i><input class="sumamtcollected form-control " name="accttotal[]" type="text" value="" readonly style="background-color:white" ></td><td></td></tr></body></table>
```

Where currentTable is

```
var currentTable = $(this).closest('table').attr('id');
```

Comment: You already use a class `.sumamtcollected` to select subtotal field, so I guess you know how to use class, so, what is your problem? Just use `.table input.sumamtcollected`?

Comment: Thanx man. I realized that i was using one extra dot which is ```table.input.sumamtcollected```, that was why it was not working.

Comment: No problem, When you separate it with space `.table .input` you are telling to select  element which has class `input` with a parent who has `.table`, When no space, then you are telling to select element with both class `table` and `input` on them.

Comment: Alright, Thanks for your help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Alternatively, you may modify your selector to query all `table`'s that have an `id` that start with `'addaccount'` like so:

```
$('table[id^="addaccount"]')
```

```js
$('table[id^="addaccount"]').each(function() {
  console.log(this);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="addaccount1" class="table table-bordered">
  <tbody>
    <tr class="invoice-total" bgcolor="#f1f1f1">
      <td colspan="3" align="right"><strong>Sub-Total</strong></td>
      <td><i class="fa fa-inr"></i><input class="sumamtcollected form-control " name="accttotal[]" type="text" value="" readonly style="background-color:white"></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    </body>
</table>
<table id="addaccount2" class="table table-bordered">
  <tbody>
    <tr class="invoice-total" bgcolor="#f1f1f1">
      <td colspan="3" align="right"><strong>Sub-Total</strong></td>
      <td><i class="fa fa-inr"></i><input class="sumamtcollected form-control " name="accttotal[]" type="text" value="" readonly style="background-color:white"></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    </body>
</table>
```